# applying a method I created for every element of an array

Tags: javascript, methods, foreach

I created this method for numbers :

```
Number.prototype.UnitConversion = function (units){
var conversion;
switch (units){
    case "Metric":
        conversion = this/100;
        break;
    case "English":
        conversion = this/12;
        break;
}
return conversion;
}
```

I want to apply it for every element of an array.

```
InnerR = [10,5,2];
InnerR.forEach(function (number){
    number.UnitConversion(unitType)
});
```

However, by doing so the elements inside the InnerR array stays unchanged. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You cannot mutate Number objects in place, so use `map`, not `forEach` and assign: `InnerR = InnerR.map(n => n.whatever())`

Comment: the function passed inside forEach or map will call that function with the copy of that element of array. So in case you have array of objects, it would have passed object reference to that inner function and the moment you change that copied object value it would have reflected on your original array. But in your case you have array of numbers, so forEach will call that function with each copied number now if you are changing these numbers it will not affect original array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
InnerR.forEach((number, index, arr) => arr[index] = number.UnitConversion(unitType));
```

However, it would be better to create new array with new values instead of direct manipulation:

```
const newArray = InnerR.map(number => number.UnitConversion(unitType));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`. This will return a new array with relevant values.If you want to use `forEach` you need to remove the current element and update the index with new value.

```js
Number.prototype.UnitConversion = function(units) {
  var conversion;
  switch (units) {
    case "Metric":
      conversion = this / 100;
      break;
    case "English":
      conversion = this / 12;
      break;
  }
  return conversion;
}

let inner = [10, 5, 2];
let modArray = inner.map(function(number) {
  return number.UnitConversion("Metric")
});
console.log(modArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the result of the conversion, but when you call the method you're ignoring this result. Use `map` not `forEach`

```js
Number.prototype.UnitConversion = function (units){
    var conversion;
    switch (units){
        case "Metric":
            conversion = this/100;
            break;
        case "English":
            conversion = this/12;
            break;
    }
    return conversion;
}

var InnerR = [10,5,2];
var convertedInnerR = InnerR.map(function (number){
    return number.UnitConversion("Metric");
});

console.log(convertedInnerR);
```

Comment: What would the for each be useful for then?

Comment: @PhilippeGauthier for doing an operation on each element of an array. But not so much for creating a new array.

Comment: @PhilippeGauthier `forEach` is pretty useless, you'd rather use `for of` instead

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `forEach` anonymous function, I added the `index` parameter and used this to replace the current value with the conversion.

```
InnerR.forEach(function (number, index){
    InnerR[index] = number.UnitConversion('English');
});
```